# How to change the target directory for debian:packageBin?

Tags: sbt

I use [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)'s `debian:packageBin` task that produces files under `target/<app name>/`.

How I can change the produced directory into other path, such as `/usr/local/` in the computer, rather than the `target/`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `target in Debian` in `build.sbt`:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import NativePackagerKeys._

packageArchetype.java_application

target in Debian := file("/usr/local/")

packageDescription in Debian := "My package Description"
```

I don't think you want it, though, since it links `/usr/local` with the project for `debian` build artifacts and the directory can end up with files you don't really want there.